# How to change header and footer for odoo enterprise default report e.g. Profit and loss, Balance Sheet in PDF format

Tags: pdf, odoo, odoo-9

I am using odoo 9 enterprise version.

I have to customize header and footer of accounting reports e.g. Profit and loss, Balance Sheet in PDF file.

I searched a lot but seems helpless to customized header and footer.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you trying to your customized add header and footer for only accounting reports or All odoo reports?

Comment: Yes, For enterprise version i want to change header and footer for those account reports.

Answer (score -1):

in Account reports where ever header and footer is not coming there odoo using to call report.internal_layout.by inheriting those report change report.external_layout.
this is my code for custom header and footer by inheriting odoo header and footer.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<odoo>
    <data>
        <template id="external_layout_header_inherit_cr" 
            inherit_id="report.external_layout_header">
            <xpath expr="//div[@class='header']" position="replace">
                <div class="header">
                    <!-- you're code here -->
                </div>
            </xpath>
        </template>
        <template id="external_layout_footer_inherit_cr" 
            inherit_id="report.external_layout_footer">
            <xpath expr="//div[@class='footer']" position="replace">
                <div class="footer">
                    <!-- you're code here -->
                </div>
            </xpath>
        </template>
    </data>
</odoo>
```

now i'm changing odoo financial report by inherting it.

```
<template id="report_financial_inherit" 
            inherit_id="module_name.inherit_id">
            <xpath expr="//t[@t-call='report.internal_layout']" position="replace">
                <!-- here they are calling internal report only but i'm using 
                external layout becoz in external layout i have header and footer  -->
                <t t-call="report.external_layout">
                    <div class="page">
                        <!--add oddo financial report code/ your custom code-->
                    </div>
                </t>
            </xpath>
        </template>
```

I hope you understand what actually work..or do.